# If-else loop to find solution

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    float timeLeavingTP;
    int transitNumber;
    float transitTime;
    printf("Please enter the time leaving TP.\n");
    scanf_s("%f",&timeLeavingTP);
    printf("Please enter bus number.\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&transitNumber);
    if(timeLeavingTP==1.00)
    {

        if(transitNumber==27)
        {
        transitTime=1.56;
        }
        else if(transitNumber==8);
        {
        transitTime=1.39;
        }
    }
    if(timeLeavingTP==6.30)
    {
        if(transitNumber==27)
        {
        transitTime=7.32;
        }
        else if(transitNumber==8)
        {
        transitTime=7.29;
        }
    printf("The time reached home is %f\n",transitTime);
    }
}
```

After debugging i got

```
Please enter the time leaving TP
1.00
Please enter bus number
27
Please enter to continue...
```

My question is How do i adjust the program to make it look like the one below instead. What kind of error did i commit?

```
Please enter the time leaving TP
1.00
Please enter bus number
27
The time reached home is 1.56
```

Thanks for the help in advance!
Hi guys after including == i still got the same for my debugging? Is there something else that i did wrong?

Comment: `timeLeavingTP=1.00` is an assignment. To compare use `if(timeLeavingTP==1.00)`.

Comment: `void main()` is invalid

Comment: `if(timeLeavingTP==6.30);` the semicolon does that nothing happens even if the if-calse is fulfilled.

Comment: Consider using `std::map<int, float>` to map transit numbers to times.

Comment: You need to use "else if" instead of "else".

Comment: You definitely need to learn more about the language

Comment: Note that your edit does not solve points 2, 3 or 4 in my answer.

Comment: Yes. Check my answer or read carefully @shart's answer

Comment: Hi @sharth Thanks for the help! Does it mean that i cannot put a if-else loop into another if-else loop?

Comment: `if` is not a loop. Loops loop, `if` doesn't.

Comment: @Newprogrammer258 You can. Just replace `else` with `else if(cond)`

Comment: Are you sure do did not read a book on C instead of C++ on accident?

Comment: @Quest Oh i see! Hmm seems like theres someething wrong with my second part of the programming from if(timeLeavingTP==6.30); onward because when i remove the parts belonging to if(timeLeavingTP==6.30) , the program works normally for timeLeavingTP==1.00

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yup! I've check it's a C++

Comment: @Newprogrammer258 Yes because you need to remove `;` at the end of the line

Comment: @Quest Oh i see! Hmm but after removing the cloumn i'll be able to type the time leaving and the bus number but there is no result coming out hmm whats the problem?

Answer (score 5):

## Part 1: `=` vs `==`

Note that:

```
if(timeLeavingTP=1.00)
```

Does not do what you expect. It assigns timeLeavingTP with 1.00.

You probably want:

```
if(timeLeavingTP==1.00)
```

Additionally, note that this error occurs 6 times in your program.

## Part 2: comparing floating point numbers

Your code might work in this case, but I'm not 100% sure if it will or not. It's often difficult to directly compare 2 floating point numbers, because of the inaccuracy of storing them (for example, 0.1 is usually not representable in floating point).

Most people solve this problem in one of a few ways:

1. Test a range around the number.
2. Convert to some fixes width format. Perhaps you could store the number as an integer, knowing that it's representation is actually 0.01 * the stored number.
3. In this case, you could actually just store the information as strings, and compare those.

## Part 3: conditionals

To write a proper conditional, it should look like:

```
if (condition) {
    ...
} else if (condition) {
    ...
} else if (condition) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

You can certainly nest conditionals as well:

```
if (condition) {
    if (condition) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else if (condition) {
    ...
}
```

Your code, for example, messes this up when you do:

```
    } 
    else(transitNumber=8);
    {
        transitTime=1.39;
    }
```

Note that the else statement does not accept a conditional after it.

## Part 4: excessive semicolons

Additionally, note that after the else and if statements there are no semicolons. The semicolons only appear within the braces. So this statement:

```
if(timeLeavingTP=6.30);
```

While semantically valid, does not do what you expect. You actually want to remove that semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(timeLeavingTP == 1.00)
{

    if(transitNumber == 27)
    {
       transitTime=1.56;
    }
    else if(transitNumber == 8)
    {
       transitTime=1.39;
    }
}
else if(timeLeavingTP == 6.30)
{
    if(transitNumber == 27)
    {
       transitTime == 7.32;
    }
    if(transitNumber ==8)
    {
        transitTime=7.29;
    }
}
 printf("The time reached home is %f\n",transitTime);
```

}

Comment: You missed a stray `;` on the else if

Comment: @NeilKirk No he didn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(transitNumber=27)
{
    transitTime=1.56;
}
else(transitNumber=8);
{
    transitTime=1.39;  //this line is executed all the time
}
```

This code is completly invalid!
First, you do not compare anything... `transitNumber = 27` is an assignment.
Second `else(transitNumber=8);` again this is an assignment and it should be `else if(...)`.  Also `;` at the and means that `transitTime = 1.39`(inside bracket) will always happen, even if `transitNumber != 8`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(timeLeavingTP=1.00)
```

to

```
if(timeLeavingTP==1.00)
```

so that you can compare timeLeavingTP correctly.